# htop: Using Ctrl + n & Ctrl + p to move between processes

Tags: osx, keyboard-shortcuts, htop

I'm running the latest version of `htop` through Homebrew on the latest OSX. `htop` seems to work well on my terminal (either Terminal or iTerm), but:

I'm unable to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> to move up and down between processes.

Comment: Is this the issue? [Arrow keys don't work in htop on OS X in Terminal](http://superuser.com/questions/130155/arrow-keys-dont-work-in-htop-on-os-x-in-terminal)

Comment: Thanks @slm - That's a different problem that I don't have. I think newer versions of OS X fixed that problem.

Comment: OK, will keep looking.

Comment: htop doesn't use readline. Do the arrow keys work in htop?

Comment: Thanks @Gilles. Yes - the arrow keys work perfectly well, and I have no problem using C-n and C-p on the terminal to navigate through commands, moving between lines in Emacs (`-nw`), etc.